# Informatica MD5 function vs SQL Hashbytes MD5 function

Tags: sql-server-2012, informatica, cryptography

I am hoping someone has some crossover experience here.  I am attempting to utilize the [Hashbytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function within SQL to match a value that is being generated utilizing the MD5 function from Informatica.

Has anyone ever been dove into this issue? My first assumption is that since the systems are different, the actual calculation of the `checksum` might have minute differences. It also could be how I am attempting to concatenate the values prior to using the `hashbytes` MD5 function.

I am at a loss, and am beginning to think it won't ever be possible to match these values (as many have said online) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have access to an informatica system, then just run the functions on a sample of random strings and compare? Is there a reason you can't do this? The md5 function is well-defined and any two implementations should give you the same result. It is no longer considered suitable for crypto but good enough for file transfer verifications and such (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5))!

Comment: I do not have access is the issue.  I may have someone run the function on a simple string, and I do the same on the SQL side, to see if I can at least get the same result.  If I can, then I know it's possible.

Comment: I would have thought that md5 from reputable vendor 1 = md5 from rv2? Just my humble opinion. Unfortunately, a search came up with no fiddles for Informatica. Can you download and install an instance of the relevant product? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: And it very well could be - I did find this, while not exact, is still somewhat discouraging https://kb.informatica.com/faq/7/Pages/14/323034.aspx.  And thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: Not sure if your link indicates a problem with Informatica code. It's an interesting question (+1). Lemme know how it pans out (@ + Vérace here - no space - will notify me). Trial download?

Comment: Did some work Friday afternoon @Vérace, what I was generating as a hash for a simple two word phrase (concatenated) was the same as what Informatica generated using the MD5 function....So it looks like concatenation isn't the issue here, it is the actual values we are using to compute the hash.  I will keep you updated.

Comment: `was the same as what Informatica generated` - was the **same**!! So, what's the problem? md5(string_x) in SQL Server is the same as md5(string_x) in Informatica - where's the issue? What does `concatenation isn't the issue here` mean in this context?

Comment: So, I believe the phrase we used was tennis and court.  I was concerned the way I was doing it via SQL, which is: `select HashBytes('md5', 'Tennis'+'Court')` could be concatenating the value differently than how Informatica is doing it:  `MD5('Tennis'||'Court') `.

However, that is not the case, since I got the same values.  That means the issue is with the actual values I am  attempting to concatenate.  Hashbytes doesn't allow an MD5 of an actual date field, so that could pose an issue for me. My research continues.

Comment: Double pipe (`||`) is the SQL standard operator for string concatenation. I believe that some servers (can't remember offhand) may also use the `+` operator. If the string being md5'ed is `Tennis Count` no matter how you construct it **and** you're apparently seeing that the hash is the same, then you're golden AFAICS.